# Magento 1.8 - How to use reference to show a template on all pages without using a custom module?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, design, view, reference

I try to add the following template on all pages in the header by using reference. I tried it like this:

> **app/design/frontend/venedor/default/template/black/alert/index.phtml:**

```
<script>alert("Hello world!")</script>
```

> app/design/frontend/venedor/default/layout/alert.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="newsletter_alert" as="newsletter_alert" template="black/alert/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But no alert is shown. Why does it not work?

---

I know I can add my block as child block to `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">` in `app/design/frontend/{{packageName}}/default/layout/page.xml`. I already tried this and it works.

But my question is about how to do solve this by using the XML tag `reference` from another layout file e.g. from (`app/design/frontend/venedor/default/layout/alert.xml`) .

---

Comment: I think it should be header.

Comment: @kunj, no and it makes no difference. I just tried it.

Comment: but head for page `title, script, css and meta` tag.

Comment: Yes, but my template is only a script tag? So head should be fine or not?

Comment: I think you are tried in magento2?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am using Magento 1.8

Comment: @Black , https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132852/add-content-before-footer . It will help you

Comment: @ChiragRajput, The question which you have linked asks how to solve this with a module. Do you linked to it because you say that it only works with a module and what I try is not possible?

Comment: @Black can you update the your config.xml file? my guess is you didn't include the alert.xml in your config.xml.

Comment: @Sathish, which config.xml, where is it located at?

Comment: @Black where you added the alert.xml? if you located the `app/design/frontend/venedor/default/layout/alert.xml` file its doesn't help, here you need to mention alert.xml in your respective module.

Comment: @Sathish, Which module? I try to do it without module as the question title says...

Comment: @Black that cases you need to use local.xml or any other xml which is already mentioned in module. in your case you didn't mention alert.xml in none of config.xml files, then how magento know to read?

Comment: @Sathish, where is `local.xml` located?

Comment: @Black have a look https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26347/incorrect-loading-order-of-layout-xml and change alert.xml to local.xml it works.

Comment: @Sathish, this does not answer where the file `local.xml` is located at. Is it at `app/etc/local.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

TRy below code.

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <reference name="top.container">
            <block type="core/template" name="newsletter_alert"  template="black/alert/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </reference>
<default>
```

Open `header.phtml` And Put this code before `div`.

```
<div class="header-language-background">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter_alert') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your alternative solution. But I don't understand how this answers my question which is about using `reference` to solve this.

Comment: I edit code try above

Comment: try via local.xml

Comment: Putting the `reference` code in `app/design/frontend/{{package}}/default/layout/layout.xml` made it work! But I am wondering why does it not work with my custom .xml file `app/design/frontend/{{package}}/default/layout/alert.xml`? Maybe it does only work in combination with a custom module? If you can answer this then I can finish this topic and accept your solution.

Comment: make a local.xml file in your custom theme and put code i suggest
app/design/frontend/{{package}}/default/layout/local.xml

Comment: It does still not answer why it was not working with my custom layout file in the same folder as the layout.xml file.

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: `alert.xml` needs to be loaded before it gets parsed. If no module is associated with the file, it wont get loaded. `local.xml` is _always_ loaded as it's definition is part of the Magento core.

Comment: @Rian, So I need to create a custom module to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="newsletter_alert"  template="black/alert/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And add this code:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter_alert') ?>`

in

`app/design/frontend/{{theme package name}}/{{theme name}}/template/page/html/header.phtml`

If it is not there then copy and paste in theme.

Comment: I tried it, but it does still not work. No alert shows.

Comment: add your XML code in `local.xml`.

Comment: Yes, I know I can add my block as child block to `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">` but my question is about how to do this by using `reference` from another layout file.

Answer (score 0):

TRy below code.

```
<default> 
       <reference name="after_body_start">
                <block type="core/template" name="newsletter_alert" as="newsletter_alert" template="black/alert/index.phtml" />
       </reference> 
<default>
```

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: @Black, answer upadted try now